# Association rules for congressional votes with missing values

Tags: association-rules

Using the UCI dataset here: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Congressional+Voting+Records

Each congressperson votes yay, nay or present (basically abstains) on 16 issues.
My teacher wants us to treat missing values (vote present) as a third category.
So I thought of making a new column for each vote.
So columns for votes 1 to 16 are either 1 for yay or 0 for nay and no value or NaN for abstaining.
Then the new 16 columns called abstention are either 1 if the corresponding vote column was a NaN or no value and 0 otherwise.
We can use up to 3 items to find some associations.

Is the above correct method to create a third category?
Then when I search associations using Python apyori or R, do I include 3 pairs of (vote, abstention)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, given your teacher's request, you should not record abstain votes as missing values, but rather as a distinct third category. So for every question you have a factor variable with three levels. Otherwise many routines would just ignore the abstain votes instead of including them in the calculations.

Comment: oh, I see so for association rules I need to binarize so there would be six classes.  is yay, is not yay, is nay, is not nay, is abstain, is not abstain?

Comment: actually three would do, is yay, is nay, is abstain

Comment: Yes, three dummy variables will do. There is a handy function for this in Python: `pandas.get_dummies()`.

Comment: haha, I spent so much time making the dummy variables manually before seeing this.  And I didn't even do it right.